# What should we write for tenth segment in .Htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

```
RewriteRule ^products/(\d+)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([^_]+)-_([^.]+)_([^.]+)_([^.]+)_([^.]+)_([^.]+).html$  /$5-$6-$7-$8-$9-$10/p$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

The above redirect rule redirects me from this URL

```
http://www.example.com/products/44/category/sub_category/sub_to_sub_category/product_name_with_multiple_under_scores.html
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/product-name-with-multiple-under-440/p44
```

In the above redirect rule the last character of the product name(scores) is read as segment $1 i.e 44 and "0" is appended to it.

My question is what should we write for tenth segment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access more than 9 grouped parts within RewriteRule, as per the mod_rewrite docs:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

So to achieve what you're after, you can just group together some of your existing groups to bring the total under 10. In your example, you're not using matches $2, $3, and $4, so you can group those together with no issue:

```
RewriteRule ^products/(\d+)/((.*)/(.*)/(.*))/([^_]+)-_([^.]+)_([^.]+)_([^.]+)_([^.]+)_([^.]+).html$  /$3-$4-$5-$6-$7-$8/p$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: I grouped the common segments but "$3" still reads the 3rd segment.

Comment: Alternately try this: `RewriteRule ^products/(\d+)/(.*)/([^_]+)-_([^.]+)_([^.]+)_([^.]+)_([^.]+)_([^.]+).html$  /$3-$4-$5-$6-$7-$8/p$1 [L,NC,R=301]`